# Error in compiling a Linux kernel

Tags: linux-kernel, compilation

**How do you read the errors?**

I run after having .config -file at /home/aal/build/kernel.

```
/usr/src/linux-2.6$ make O=/home/aal/build/kernel/
```

I get

```
  ... cut ...
  CC [M]  drivers/staging/go7007/s2250-board.o
/usr/src/linux-2.6/drivers/staging/go7007/s2250-board.c:24:26: error: s2250-loader.h: No such file or directory
/usr/src/linux-2.6/drivers/staging/go7007/s2250-board.c: In function ‘read_reg_fp’:
/usr/src/linux-2.6/drivers/staging/go7007/s2250-board.c:264: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘down_interruptible’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/src/linux-2.6/include/linux/semaphore.h:43: note: expected ‘struct semaphore *’ but argument is of type ‘struct mutex *’
/usr/src/linux-2.6/drivers/staging/go7007/s2250-board.c:273: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘up’ from incompatible pointer type
/usr/src/linux-2.6/include/linux/semaphore.h:47: note: expected ‘struct semaphore *’ but argument is of type ‘struct mutex *’
/usr/src/linux-2.6/drivers/staging/go7007/s2250-board.c: In function ‘s2250_init’:
/usr/src/linux-2.6/drivers/staging/go7007/s2250-board.c:670: error: implicit declaration of function ‘s2250loader_init’
/usr/src/linux-2.6/drivers/staging/go7007/s2250-board.c:676: error: implicit declaration of function ‘s2250loader_cleanup’
make[4]: *** [drivers/staging/go7007/s2250-board.o] Error 1
make[3]: *** [drivers/staging/go7007] Error 2
make[2]: *** [drivers/staging] Error 2
make[1]: *** [drivers] Error 2
make: *** [sub-make] Error 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the reference to that driver from your .config and the issue will go away. Alternately if you need the driver appropriate the source.

All of those errors are caused by the missing header.

Comment: **How can you remove the reference to the file in the .config?** I did not find any driver with the given name. - I also tried to remove the given file, but some files are dependent on it so it cannot just be removed.

Comment: You can't just remove the files in question. Can you paste up your .config? Or a pastebin link to it? Only too happy to help then :)

Answer (score 1):

The errors are in a *staging* driver, i.e. either *not yet*, or *already not* stable driver (take a look e.g. [here](http://lwn.net/Articles/357805/) for a discussion of the staging tree.) You can disable these in kernel config *Device Drivers --> Staging Drivers*.

Answer (score 0):

The errors probably all stem from the missing file in the first error.

I'd suspect include path or incomplete install of the sources...